# How to use lerp to change position?

Tags: unity, c#

At the top I have a float duration and float t.
Also at the top a Rect rectangleReference.

Then in the OnGUI I'm making first a reference to drawn rect

```
rectangleReference = rect;
```

and myCube is a reference so simple 3d cube.

Then doing the Lerp position change

```
DrawScreenRectBorder(rectangleReference, 2, Color.cyan);
var cubeworld = WorldToGuiPoint(myCube.position);
t += Time.deltaTime / duration;
rectangleReference.center = Vector3.Lerp(rectangleReference.center, cubeworld, t);
```

Doing this way the rectangleReference is moving to the cubeworld but at once not smooth slowly as lerp should be working the duration this way have no affect.

Before that I tried it this way

```
rectangleReference.center = Vector3.Lerp(rectangleReference.position, cubeworld, t);
```

This way the lerp is working but the is start moving from another position and nto from where the drawn rect is.

The method WorldToGuiPoint

```
public Vector3 WorldToGuiPoint(Vector3 position)
    {
        var guiPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        guiPosition.y = Screen.height - guiPosition.y;

        return guiPosition;
    }
```

The complete script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SC_SelectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform myCube;
    public Texture topLeftBorder;
    public Texture bottomLeftBorder;
    public Texture topRightBorder;
    public Texture bottomRightBorder;
    public float duration;

    private Rect rectangleReference;
    private float t = 0;

    Texture2D _borderTexture;
    Texture2D borderTexture
    {
        get
        {
            if (_borderTexture == null)
            {
                _borderTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
                _borderTexture.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.white);
                _borderTexture.Apply();
            }

            return _borderTexture;
        }
    }

    bool selectionStarted = false;
    Vector3 mousePosition1;

    public static List<SC_Selectable> selectables = new List<SC_Selectable>();
    List<int> selectedObjects = new List<int>();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Begin selection
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            selectionStarted = true;
            mousePosition1 = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        // End selection
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            selectionStarted = false;
        }

        if (selectionStarted)
        {
            // Detect which Objects are inside selection rectangle
            Camera camera = Camera.main;
            selectedObjects.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < selectables.Count; i++)
            {
                Bounds viewportBounds = GetViewportBounds(camera, mousePosition1, Input.mousePosition);
                if (viewportBounds.Contains(camera.WorldToViewportPoint(selectables[i].transform.position)))
                {
                    selectedObjects.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (selectionStarted)
        {
            Rect rect = GetScreenRect(mousePosition1, Input.mousePosition);
            DrawScreenRectBorder(rect, 2, Color.cyan);

            rectangleReference = rect;
        }
        else
        {
            DrawScreenRectBorder(rectangleReference, 2, Color.cyan);
            var cubeworld = WorldToGuiPoint(myCube.position);
            t += Time.deltaTime / duration;
            rectangleReference.center = Vector3.Lerp(rectangleReference.center, cubeworld, t);
            //rectangleReference.center = cubeworld;
        }

        // Draw selection edges
        if (selectedObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            Camera camera = Camera.main;
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                DrawSelectionIndicator(camera, selectables[selectedObjects[i]].GetObjectBounds());
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector3 WorldToGuiPoint(Vector3 position)
    {
        var guiPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        guiPosition.y = Screen.height - guiPosition.y;

        return guiPosition;
    }

    void DrawScreenRectBorder(Rect rect, float thickness, Color color)
    {
        // Top
        DrawBorderRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMin, rect.width, thickness), color);
        // Left
        DrawBorderRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMin, thickness, rect.height), color);
        // Right
        DrawBorderRect(new Rect(rect.xMax - thickness, rect.yMin, thickness, rect.height), color);
        // Bottom
        DrawBorderRect(new Rect(rect.xMin, rect.yMax - thickness, rect.width, thickness), color);
    }

    void DrawBorderRect(Rect rect, Color color)
    {
        GUI.color = color;
        GUI.DrawTexture(rect, borderTexture);
        GUI.color = Color.white;
    }

    Rect GetScreenRect(Vector3 screenPosition1, Vector3 screenPosition2)
    {
        // Move origin from bottom left to top left
        screenPosition1.y = Screen.height - screenPosition1.y;
        screenPosition2.y = Screen.height - screenPosition2.y;
        // Calculate corners
        var topLeft = Vector3.Min(screenPosition1, screenPosition2);
        var bottomRight = Vector3.Max(screenPosition1, screenPosition2);
        // Create Rect
        return Rect.MinMaxRect(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y);
    }

    Bounds GetViewportBounds(Camera camera, Vector3 screenPosition1, Vector3 screenPosition2)
    {
        Vector3 v1 = camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(screenPosition1);
        Vector3 v2 = camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(screenPosition2);
        Vector3 min = Vector3.Min(v1, v2);
        Vector3 max = Vector3.Max(v1, v2);
        min.z = camera.nearClipPlane;
        max.z = camera.farClipPlane;

        Bounds bounds = new Bounds();
        bounds.SetMinMax(min, max);
        return bounds;
    }

    void DrawSelectionIndicator(Camera camera, Bounds bounds)
    {
        Vector3 boundPoint1 = bounds.min;
        Vector3 boundPoint2 = bounds.max;
        Vector3 boundPoint3 = new Vector3(boundPoint1.x, boundPoint1.y, boundPoint2.z);
        Vector3 boundPoint4 = new Vector3(boundPoint1.x, boundPoint2.y, boundPoint1.z);
        Vector3 boundPoint5 = new Vector3(boundPoint2.x, boundPoint1.y, boundPoint1.z);
        Vector3 boundPoint6 = new Vector3(boundPoint1.x, boundPoint2.y, boundPoint2.z);
        Vector3 boundPoint7 = new Vector3(boundPoint2.x, boundPoint1.y, boundPoint2.z);
        Vector3 boundPoint8 = new Vector3(boundPoint2.x, boundPoint2.y, boundPoint1.z);

        Vector2[] screenPoints = new Vector2[8];
        screenPoints[0] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint1);
        screenPoints[1] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint2);
        screenPoints[2] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint3);
        screenPoints[3] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint4);
        screenPoints[4] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint5);
        screenPoints[5] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint6);
        screenPoints[6] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint7);
        screenPoints[7] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(boundPoint8);

        Vector2 topLeftPosition = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 topRightPosition = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 bottomLeftPosition = Vector2.zero;
        Vector2 bottomRightPosition = Vector2.zero;

        for (int a = 0; a < screenPoints.Length; a++)
        {
            //Top Left
            if (topLeftPosition.x == 0 || topLeftPosition.x > screenPoints[a].x)
            {
                topLeftPosition.x = screenPoints[a].x;
            }
            if (topLeftPosition.y == 0 || topLeftPosition.y > Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y)
            {
                topLeftPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y;
            }
            //Top Right
            if (topRightPosition.x == 0 || topRightPosition.x < screenPoints[a].x)
            {
                topRightPosition.x = screenPoints[a].x;
            }
            if (topRightPosition.y == 0 || topRightPosition.y > Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y)
            {
                topRightPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y;
            }
            //Bottom Left
            if (bottomLeftPosition.x == 0 || bottomLeftPosition.x > screenPoints[a].x)
            {
                bottomLeftPosition.x = screenPoints[a].x;
            }
            if (bottomLeftPosition.y == 0 || bottomLeftPosition.y < Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y)
            {
                bottomLeftPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y;
            }
            //Bottom Right
            if (bottomRightPosition.x == 0 || bottomRightPosition.x < screenPoints[a].x)
            {
                bottomRightPosition.x = screenPoints[a].x;
            }
            if (bottomRightPosition.y == 0 || bottomRightPosition.y < Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y)
            {
                bottomRightPosition.y = Screen.height - screenPoints[a].y;
            }
        }

        if (topLeftBorder != null && topRightBorder != null &&
            bottomLeftBorder != null && bottomRightBorder != null)
        {
            /*GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(topLeftPosition.x - 16, topLeftPosition.y - 16, 16, 16), topLeftBorder);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(topRightPosition.x, topRightPosition.y - 16, 16, 16), topRightBorder);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(bottomLeftPosition.x - 16, bottomLeftPosition.y, 16, 16), bottomLeftBorder);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(bottomRightPosition.x, bottomRightPosition.y, 16, 16), bottomRightBorder);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to reset `t` to 0 each time you release the mouse?

Comment: There's a number of issues with your script (no offense, we have all started some time). But before we go into depth: what exactly are you trying to achieve? This looks horribly complicated for - yes, for what? @NCoolgamer 's answer - as helpful as ist is - scratches but the surface...

Comment: @loptrinho The main goal is to make a rectangle with the mouse around object so the rectangle will be the distance limitation the object in the rectangle can move to.  I mean after drawing a rectangle around some object if the object then start to move he will not be able to leave the rectangle area.

Comment: @loptrinho and the Lerp is just an option. I will a bool flag later if true the rectangle should move smooth slowly so the object will be in the center of the rectangle this is what the lerp is for with or without lerp and if the flag is false the rectangle I draw will stay as it is. but the main goal is in my first comment.

Comment: @loptrinho the rectangle is like a wall a block and by drawing it you decide how the block will looks like and what is the distance the object can move inside the area.

Comment: @loptrinho what do you think ?

Comment: Still not easy to imagine without visual help, but I think, I get the idea. This still sounds quite complicated, but for a start, this could work, and @NCoolgamer's answer should do the trick for now (I guess, your code will change a lot before you publish this, so don't worry too much at this time).

Comment: There's one or two basic things, though, I'd like to point out. You might want to read about OOP principles a bit and then keep your editor reference private with `SerializeField` attributes. Also, you are using two different methods now to update your objects, and you don't need the `Update()`. Did you know that you can use `Input.Get...()` not only in `Update()`? You could move all of your respective code to `OnGui()`. This page might be interesting to you: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: And please don't use `Camera.main`, try to avoid it at all costs. Though Unity have improved on it, it is still expensive and should **never** be used in `Update()`or alike. If you cannot avoid it, cache the reference. Better still, don't use it and give your script a direct reference to the camera you intend to use, or implement a `SetCamera()` method to pass a camera reference in. Have fun and keep on learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code in your `OnGUI`:

`rectangleReference.center = Vector3.Lerp(rectangleReference.center, cubeworld, t);`

sets the `rectangleReference.center` each time it is executed, which is used as the new starting point for [`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) next time it is called, which makes the movement incorrect.

To fix this problem, simply remember the starting `rectangleReference.center` position when you begin the movement. For example, add a private variable:

`private Vector3 rectangleStartPosition = Vector3.zero;`

Then, modify this if statement in your `Update` from this:

```
// End selection
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    selectionStarted = false;
}
```

To this:

```
// End selection
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    selectionStarted = false;
    rectangleStartPosition = rectangleReference.center; // Remember the current position. Do that elsewhere if you need to start the movement from a different position.
    t = 0; // I assume that you want to reset the movement when you release the mouse
}
```

Finally, in the `OnGUI` method, change the line of code with the lerp to:

```
rectangleReference.center = Vector3.Lerp(rectangleStartPosition, cubeworld, t);
```

Also, [`rectangleReference.center`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-center.html) and [`rectangleReference.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-position.html) are different, with `rectangleReference.center` defining the center of the rectangle, and `rectangleReference.position` defining its top left corner.

Comment: After the changes I made, now it's not drawing a rectangle at all.  I added the changed script to pastebin.com at this link https://pastebin.com/37HkYN0S

Comment: I think that you've removed the if statement that checked for `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`, which made it so `selectionStarted` is always set to false and t is always set to 0 on every update